# Segmentation fault while taking input in a 2d array in C++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

The computer is giving segmentation fault whenever I try to read input into this. My input looks like:

```
7
1 2 3
2 3 1
1 4 4
4 6 7
7 5 2
3 5 1
4 5 5
```

Basically, I want to store the above input directly into a 2D array. The first column is X-coordinates, 2nd column Y-coordinate and finally the value needed to store in (X,Y) COORDINATE of a 2D array.

```
long leastTimeToInterview(int n, int k, int m) {
    int a[m+1][m+1];
    int i=0,x=0,y=0;

    for (i=1;i<=m;i++){
        scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
        scanf("%d",&a[x][y]);
        a[y][x]=a[x][y];

    } 
    return 11; 
}
```

Comment: so what happens if `x` or `y` are out of bounds?

Comment: Variable length arrays is not  C++

Comment: `n` is not used here. maybe you mean `int a[m+1][n+1]`?

Comment: Does the segfault appear after the first or the second `scanf `?

Comment: The problem is that m and n are of very big size m<10^5.

Comment: segmentation fault appears after 2nd scanf.

Comment: You're getting a Stack Overflow. That's why variable length arrays are a bad idea.

Comment: Use `std::vector`.

Comment: @rustyx how do I fix it? Using dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: Use `std::vector`.

Comment: If most of the fields aren't used you might also use a `std::map`

Comment: BTW_ array indexes start at 0, not at 1.

Comment: Please show a [MCVE]

Comment: a[y][x]=a[x][y]; most probably error is coming from this statement.. what if y > m+1 or x > m+1

Comment: If `m` is 10^5, the size of `a` is around 40 gigabytes. You’re almost certainly not expected to use an array here.

Answer (score 0):

Like rustyx mentioned, this error could be a result of a stack overflow.

The easiest aproach would be to reduce the size of your array or use another data structure which allocates memory dynamically like `std::vector`, `std::list` or `std::map`.

In your example it also looks as if most of your array is empty. In this case i sugest using `std::map`.
Some other optimisations in regard of memory usage are discussed in this question: [Any optimization for random access on a very big array when the value in 95% of cases is either 0 or 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50323522/any-optimization-for-random-access-on-a-very-big-array-when-the-value-in-95-of/50348498#50348498)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as dynamically sized array in C++'s type system so you need to change it to somthing else like std::vector. The other problem is that even if your compiler supports dynamically sized arrays you still get stack overflow (at least it's very likely). So I suggest that you change your function to something like this:

```
long leastTimeToInterview(int n, int k, int m) {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> a(m + 1, std::vector<int>(m + 1));
    int i = 0, x = 0, y = 0;

    for(i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
        scanf("%d", &a[x][y]);
        a[y][x] = a[x][y];
    }
    return 11;
}
```

There still might be an error in the logic of your application but your example and explanation don't give enough information to tell that.